# I keep reading about sea buckthorn in sandy soil, can I plant them in rich black soil for better results?

Tags: planting, berries

I have a part of the yard that is incredibly rich top soil, can I plant them in the soil to give them the initial boost for a few years?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sea buckthorn loves, loves, loves *light and airy*, nutrient-poor soil, the sandier the better. They handle dry spells, but not permanently "wet feet". Even the commercial breeds get little fertilizer, for home gardens it is recommended to fertilize for perhaps a year or two after planting, then let them mostly fend for themselves, except a light dose of compost evert other year or so.

But the really crucial bit about replanting them is - you probably won't be able to after a few years. They have a tendency to really anchor themselves and send roots (and offshoots) everywhere. And they grow *fast*! So better to think *first* where you want them, then plant. Amend the soil with lots of sand, if necessary.

Comment: That's where I was planning to try to suggest my parents plant the trees, since they have some sandy soil that has a hard time growing grass, but fill replacement dirt with compost from the neighbor's compost heap. Is it correct to understand you suggest not planting the tree with compost fill, which would make them "sick", until they grow beyond that soil?

Comment: How much worse of a root system is it compared to a conifer bush with all of their roots?

Comment: Hm, think "blackberry meets conifer"? Root-wise, that is.

Comment: And just to clarify: sea buckthorn is *not a tree, but a shrub", it grows very fast, gets between three and five meters high and gets a lot of offshoots, that means, you'll suddenly find new stalks not only around the base of the bush, but at a distance.